# Get records where today is between 2 columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So I have a `events` table with 4 records in it:

```
| id | date       | active_from |
| 1  | 2015-01-27 | 2015-01-22  |
| 2  | 2015-01-30 | 2015-01-24  |
| 3  | 2015-01-29 | 2015-01-27  |
```

I'm trying to create a simple query just to grab the records when `today is lower than or equals to date` and `today is greater than or equals to active_from`.

So when its today `2015-01-26` I want to have the records with id `1` and `2`,
because the `event` is `active` and is yet to come.

Currently I have this query:

```
select * from `events` where `active_from` <= '2015-01-26' AND `date` >= '2015-01-26'
```

But it's not working... I must be looking over something here.

Comment: What means "But it's not working"? Are both columns date types?

Comment: Yes, both date types.

Answer (score 1):

You are putting the `<` and `>` the wrong way. Have a try with this one:

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE CURDATE() BETWEEN active_from AND `date`
```

Comment: Well thanks, I'm not sure what went wrong cause I tried this. Seemed like when I update the query in `phpmyadmin` it won't refresh the records..

Comment: It's also important to have the arguments to `between` in the right order. `BETWEEN date AND active_from` would not yield results, since `date > active_from`. Maybe that was your mistake?